# Jump from one XML tag to the closing one

Tags: vim, xml

Is there a shortcut to jump from, e.g, `<XX>` to `</XX>`?

I already gave it a try with <kbd>%</kbd>, but it doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: I think you'll need a plugin like [matchit](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) in order to be able to match XML tags.  `matchit` itself seems to come with most `vim` distributions, but you'll still have to enable it yourself.  `:help matchit-install` for more.

Comment: Related: [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- Install the `matchit` plugin (see `:help matchit-install` for instructions).
- Make sure automatic file-type detection and plugin-loading is enabled (`:filetype plugin on`).

Henceforth, whenever you edit a file detected as `xml` or `html` or some other tag-based markup language, the combination of the `matchit` plugin and the filetype plugin files will allow the `%` motion to match open and close tags.

Answer (score 44):

You can jump between tags using visual operators, for example:

1. Place the cursor on the tag.
2. Enter visual mode by pressing <kbd>v</kbd>.
3. Select the outer tag block by pressing <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> or <kbd>i</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> for the inner tag block.

Your cursor should jump forward to the matching closing HTML/XML tag. To jump backwards from closing tag, press <kbd>o</kbd> or <kbd>O</kbd> to jump to the opposite tag.

Now you can either exit visual selection by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, change it with <kbd>c</kbd> or copy it with <kbd>y</kbd>.

---

To record that action into a register, press <kbd>qq</kbd> to start recording, perform the tag jump as above (including <kbd>Esc</kbd>), press <kbd>q</kbd> to finish. Then to invoke the jump, press <kbd>@q</kbd>.

---

See more help at `:help visual-operators` or `:help v_it`:

> <kbd>at</kbd>      a `<tag> </tag>` block (with tags)
>
> <kbd>it</kbd>      inner `<tag> </tag>` block

---

Alternatively, use a plugin such as [matchit.vim](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) (See: [Using % in languages without curly braces](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/126/using-in-languages-without-curly-braces)).

---

See also:

- [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE
- [Jump to matching XML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500989/jump-to-matching-xml-tags-in-vim) at Stack Overflow SE
- [How can I find the closing HTML tag quickly in Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116362/how-can-i-find-the-close-html-tag-quickly-in-vim) at Stack Overflow SE
- [Navigating HTML tags in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6270396/navigating-html-tags-in-vim) at Stack Overflow SE
- [How to navigate between begin and end html tag?](https://superuser.com/questions/189815/vim-how-to-navigate-between-begin-and-end-html-tag) at Super User SE
- [How can I select an html tag's content in Vim?](https://superuser.com/questions/182355/how-can-i-select-an-html-tags-content-in-vim) at Super User SE

Comment: This works nicely for replacing text only inside an HTML/SVG/XML tag: `vat` then `:s/old/new/g`